# Creating action buttons from the user's input selection

Tags: r, shiny

I am creating an application in which I am trying to create action buttons from the user's input. Suppose, I have a data frame as shown.

[image]

What I am trying to do is-

1)Ask for the user name?
2) Ask him- "Select the countries" and 4 action buttons with country names.
3) If I select any country, it should again ask- select cities and show the number of cities as action buttons.
4) If I select any city it should ask for the Popular for-item as action buttons.
5) when I select any of the popular button it should show the ratings .

How to get this?

My reprex-

```
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(magrittr)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(emojifont)
library(shinyBS)
library(renv)
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboardPlus)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyjs)
library(reshape2)
library(pool)
library(shiny.info)
library(shinycssloaders)
library(shinybusy)
library(jsonlite)
library(readxl)
library(tidyverse)

dat<- read_xlsx(path = "Dummy.xlsx")
ui<- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  titlePanel("Info"),
  
  fluidRow(
    
    column( width = 4,
            panel(
              style = "overflow-y:scroll; max-height: 300px; position:relative; align: centre",
              textInput("message", label = "",
                        placeholder = "Type Message"),
              
     actionButton("send", "Send"), heading = "Smart-Advisor", status = "primary"
            ))))

# Defining Server Controls
server<- function(input, output, session)
{
  
  # Declaring and Initializing Global Variables
  i <- 1
  lvl <- reactiveVal()
  lvl(i)
  
  
  emojis<- matrix(c("India", "US","UK", "Canada"), byrow =F, nrow = 1)
  emj <- reactiveValues(em = 1 ) 
  
  #Clear Function 
  clearInput<- function()
  {
    updateTextInput(session,"message", value = "")
  }  
  
  #Invalid Function
  invalidInput<- function()
  {
    insertUI(
      selector = "#message",
      where = "beforeBegin",
      ui=div(class="chat-bubbles",
             div(class="bubble admin",
                 p("Kindly provide a valid input"))
      ), immediate = TRUE
    )
    clearInput()      
  }
  
  ind<- reactive({
    dat%>%filter(Country=="India")%>%distinct(Cities)
  })
  
  ind_2<- reactive({
    dat%>%filter(Country=="India" , Cities=="New Delhi")%>%distinct(`Popular for-Item`)
  }) 
  
  #Main fucntion
  replyMessage<- function(lvl,msg)
  {    
    switch(lvl,           
           # Check for Level 1
           if(grepl("^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z ]+[a-zA-Z]$",msg, perl=T))
           {             
             insertUI(selector = "#message", where = "beforeBegin",
                      ui= div(class="chat-bubbles",
                              div(class="bubble admin",
                                  img(),
                                  wellPanel(
                                    p("Hi",tags$b(msg),".",tags$br(), "My name is Zeta!","How are you feeling today?")), tags$br()),
                              p(actionBttn("mood1","India", icon = icon("grin"), style = "pill", color = "warning",size = "xs"),
                                actionBttn("mood2","US",icon = icon("frown-open"), style = "pill",size = "xs",color = "success" ),
                                actionBttn("mood3","UK", icon = icon("meh"),  style = "pill",size = "xs", color = "primary"),
                                actionBttn("mood4","Canada", icon = icon("meh"),  style = "pill",size = "xs", color = "primary")
                              )), immediate = TRUE)
             clearInput()
             shinyjs::disable("message")
             shinyjs::hide("send")             
             lvl(lvl + 1)             
           }, 
           
           # level 3             
             if(msg=='India')
             {
               insertUI(
                 selector = "#message",
                 where = "beforeBegin",
                 ui=div(class="chat-bubbles",
                        div(class="bubble admin",
                            img(),
                            wellPanel(
                              p("What Personal challenges are you facing?", emoji("raising_hand")))), tags$br(),
                        p(actionBttn("P1",paste(ind()[1,1]), icon=icon("user-friends"), color = "warning", style = "pill", size = "xs"),tags$br(), tags$br(),
                          actionBttn("P2",paste(ind()[2,1]),icon=icon("dollar-sign"), color = "success",style = "pill", size = "xs"),tags$br(), tags$br(),
                          actionBttn("P3",paste(ind()[3,1]),icon=icon("first-aid"), color = "primary", style = "pill", size = "xs")
                          
                        )), immediate = TRUE)
               
               shinyjs::disable("message")
               shinyjs::hide("send")
               
               lvl(lvl + 1)
               
             },
           
           if(paste(ind()[1,1])==TRUE)
           {
             insertUI(
               selector = "#message",
               where = "beforeBegin",
               ui=div(class="chat-bubbles",
                      div(class="bubble admin",
                          img(),
                          wellPanel(
                            p("What Personal challenges are you facing?", emoji("raising_hand")))), tags$br(),
                      p(actionBttn("P1",paste(ind_2()[1,1]), icon=icon("user-friends"), color = "warning", style = "pill", size = "xs"),tags$br(), tags$br(),
                        actionBttn("P2",paste(ind_2()[1,1]),icon=icon("dollar-sign"), color = "success",style = "pill", size = "xs"),tags$br(), tags$br(),
                        actionBttn("P3",paste(ind_2()[1,1]),icon=icon("first-aid"), color = "primary", style = "pill", size = "xs")
                        
                      )), immediate = TRUE)
           
           shinyjs::disable("message")
           shinyjs::hide("send")
           lvl(lvl + 1)
           }        
           ) }
  
  # Function to check blank in Message box
  getMessage<- function(lvl)
  {
    # Observer Event for Message Box
    observeEvent(input$send,{
      if(input$message == '')
      {
        insertUI(
          selector = "#message",
          where = "beforeBegin",
          ui=div(class="chat-bubbles",
                 div(class="bubble admin",
                     img(),
                     p("Kindly provide a valid input."))
          )
        )
        clearInput()
      }
      else
      {
        replyMessage(lvl(),input$message)
      }
        })   
    
    lapply(sprintf("mood%s", 1:4),
           function(x)
           {
             observeEvent(input[[x]],{
               emj$em<- as.numeric(sub("mood", "", x))
               insertUI(selector = "#message", where = "beforeBegin",
                        p(paste(
                          replyMessage(lvl(),emojis[, emj$em])))
               )
             })
             shinyjs::disable("mood1")
             shinyjs::disable("mood2")
             shinyjs::disable("mood3")
             shinyjs::disable("mood4")
           })   
    
  }
  # Main Function
  startConversation<- function()
  {
    
    clearInput()
    insertUI(
      selector = "#message",
      where = "beforeBegin",
      ui=div(class="chat-bubbles",
             div(class="bubble admin",
                 tags$div(class = "chat_avatar",
                          tags$img(src = "chat-robot.gif",
                                   class = "img-responsive")),
                 wellPanel(
                   p("Hey! Could I get your name?")
                 ))))
    getMessage(lvl)
    
  }
  startConversation()  
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Comment: Please make your code reproducible and minimal. There is an awful lot of code here that is superfluous to solving your specific problem. Also, it sounds that what you are looking to use is `renderUI()`. Here is an example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27053493/r-shiny-using-reactive-renderui-value

Comment: Removed the unwanted code.

Comment: Thanks that you try to make it more minimal. However, your code is still very long and not minimal. Could you try to shorten it further? Thanks

Comment: Hi @starja , done. Kindly check.