# R shiny: how to set selectInput that depends on the updateVarSelectInput()

Tags: r, shiny

I want to upload a `dataframe` in shiny. Shiny will first read its `colnames`, and gives the option for users to select `column`, then with this selected column, users can select the `levels` in this column, which can be used as **input** for further analysis.

It is very similar as this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27053493/r-shiny-using-reactive-renderui-value), but the selected values are **output**, which I cannot use for downstream analysis.

```
library(shiny)
myDF <- data.frame(A = 1:4, B = 3:6, C = 6:9, D = 10:13)
runApp(
  list(
    ui = fluidPage(
      uiOutput("myList"),
      uiOutput("myNumbers")
      )
    , server = function(input, output, session){
      output$myList <- renderUI({
        selectInput("compName", "Company Name:", LETTERS[1:4])
      })

      output$myNumbers <- renderUI({
        selectInput("compNo", "Product Line:", myDF[, input$compName])
      })
    }
    )
  )
```

my phsudo code is like this:

```
library(shiny)
runApp(
  list(
    ui = fluidPage(
      fileInput(inputId = "rawFile"), # Read the dataframe
      varSelectInput(inputId = "getColumn",
                     data = ""),
      selectInput(inputId = "levels",
                  choices = "")
    )
    , server = function(input, output, session){
      
      df <- reactive({
        inFile <- input$rawFile
        if (is.null(inFile)){return(NULL)}
        df <- read.csv(filepath, header = T),
        )
        return(df)
      })
      
       getColumn <- reactive({
        return(as.character(input$getColumn))
      })
      
       updateVarSelectInput(
         inputId = "getColumn",
         data = df(),
         selected = ""
       )
       
       ## my problem is here:
       updateSelectInput(
         inputId = "levels",
         choices = levels(as.factor(df[, getColumn()])),
         selected = NULL
       )
      
      })
    }
  )
)
```

Comment: Please fix your second example as it does not run because of syntax errors (check your brackets).

Comment: Hi @Bas, my second example is phsudo code, it does not work, because I don't know how to make it work. It is only used to show what I would like to do. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @Wang, I understand it does not do what you want, but currently it does not do anything. There are missing labels in the inputs and the brackets do not match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have many syntax issues here.  In the future, please ensure that you have matching brackets and it is a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  The following should work.

```
library(shiny)

ui = fluidPage(
      fileInput(inputId = "rawFile", label="File"), # Read the dataframe
      varSelectInput(inputId = "getColumn", label="Get Column", data = ""),
      selectInput(inputId = "levels", label="Levels", choices = "")
    )
server = function(input, output, session){
      
  df <- reactive({
    inFile <- input$rawFile
    if (is.null(inFile)){return(NULL)}
    read.csv(inFile$datapath, header = T)
  })
  
  observeEvent(df(),{
    updateVarSelectInput(session, inputId = "getColumn",data = df(),selected = "")
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$getColumn, {
    updateSelectInput(session,inputId = "levels", choices = levels(as.factor(df()[[input$getColumn]])),selected = NULL)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```